# there is bug in my working code.it does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

[thumbnail screenshot also attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhB12.png)i have created thumbnail in my dashboard.but these thumbnails are collapsing each others and the last thumbnail in a row showing up full screen.kindly help me

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Trending Groups</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="image/2.png">
        <p class="caption">outstanding</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="image/2.png">
        <p class="caption">outstanding</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="image/2.png">
        <p class="caption">outstanding</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="image/2.png">
        <p class="caption">outstanding</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a complete code.

Comment: Try thinking of a better title. What is going on with the images that you do not want? Then, I suggest searching with that title (stack overflow does that automatically I believe, but a search engine seems to give better results) Also, what's better than an image is working code that we can look at. For example, we do not know what your `thumbnail` class contains.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Try giving height and width to your image  also dearch in google little bit and then post your questions on this that will help you.